# How to parse a string for having line breaking

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a function which takes 3 arguments:
sentence (string), 
maxCharLen=20 (number), 
separator (string)

and transform the sentence based on the parameters.

Example

```
var sentence = "JavaScript is a prototype-based scripting language that is dynamic, weakly typed and has first-class functions."

var newSentence = breakSentence(sentence, maxCharLen=20, separator="<br>");

newSentence // JavaScript is a prototype-based  <br> scripting language that is dynamic, <br> weakly typed and has first-class functions.
```

P.S:

This is what I have tried:

```
 var breakSentence = function (sentence, maxCharLen, separator)
 {
   sentence = sentence || "javascript is a language" ;
   maxCharLen = 10 || maxCharLen; // max numb of chars for line
   separator = "<br>" || separator;

   var offset;
   var nbBreak = sentence.length // maxCharLen;
   var newSentence = "";

   for (var c = 0; c < nbBreak; c += 1)
   {
    offset = c * maxCharLen;
    newSentence += sentence.substring(offset, offset + maxCharLen) + separator;
   }

   return newSentence;
}
```

It works in this way:

```
 breakSentence()  // "javascript<br> is a lang<br>uage<br>"

 it should be:

 breakSentence()  // "javascript<br>is a <br>language"
```

Comment: Why should the result be : breakSentence()  // "javascript<br>is a <br>language"? If your maxCharLen = 10 then a break tag will be added every 10 chars. When should the <br/> tag be inserted? maybe try using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/869

```
//+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/string/wordwrap [v1.0]

String.prototype.wordWrap = function(m, b, c){
    var i, j, l, s, r;
    if(m < 1)
        return this;
    for(i = -1, l = (r = this.split("\n")).length; ++i < l; r[i] += s)
        for(s = r[i], r[i] = ""; s.length > m; r[i] += s.slice(0, j) + ((s = s.slice(j)).length ? b : ""))
            j = c == 2 || (j = s.slice(0, m + 1).match(/\S*(\s)?$/))[1] ? m : j.input.length - j[0].length
            || c == 1 && m || j.input.length + (j = s.slice(m).match(/^\S*/)).input.length;
    return r.join("\n");
};
```

usage:

```
var sentence = "JavaScript is a prototype-based scripting language that is dynamic, weakly typed and has first-class functions."
sentence.wordWrap(20, "<br>",true)
// Output "JavaScript is a <br>prototype-based <br>scripting language <br>that is dynamic, <br>weakly typed and has<br> first-class <br>functions."
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try it like that (not tested):

```
var breakSentence = function (sentence, maxCharLen, separator)
{
    var result = "";
    var index = 0;
    while (sentence.length - index > maxCharLen)
    {
        var spaceIndex = sentence.substring(index, index + maxCharLen).lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (spaceIndex < 0)    //no spaces
        {
            alert('Don\'t know what do do with substring with one long word');
            spaceIndex = maxCharLen;    //assume you want to break anyway to avoid infinite loop
        }
        result += sentence.substring(index, index + spaceIndex + 1)  + separator;
        index += spaceIndex + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Should break after spaces only now...

Comment: not tried code either, but this will wrap in the middle of a word.

Comment: additionally to a string that consists of a single long word, you must consider `i'm a string that has alongwordinthemiddle which will also result in infinite loop`. Also, if the string already contains line breaks, these should be conserved and the index should be reset so the line following line break is not unnecessary shorter that maxCharLen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to get it. It has two things you should notice:

- it first removes all the separator instances (so the reordering is completely new)
- it doesn't break words longer then maxCharLen characters.

It worked in node 0.6.10

```
var breakSentence = function (sentence, maxCharLen, separator) {
  var words = []   // array of words
    , i            // iterator
    , len          // loop
    , current = '' // current line
    , lines = []    // lines split
    ;
  sentence = sentence || "javascript is a language";
  maxCharLen = 10 || maxCharLen;
  separator = separator || "<br>";
  sentence = sentence.replace(separator, '');
  if (sentence.length < maxCharLen) return [sentence]; // no need to work if we're already within limits
  words = sentence.split(' ');
  for (i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    // lets see how we add the next word. if the current line is blank, just add it and move on.
    if (current == '') {
      current += words[i];
    // if it's not like that, we need to see if the next word fits the current line
    } else if (current.length + words[i].length <= maxCharLen) { // if the equal part takes the space into consideration
      current += ' ' + words[i];
    // if the next word doesn't fit, start on the next line.
    } else {
      lines.push(current);
      current = words[i];
      // have to check if this is the last word
      if (i === len -1) {
        lines.push(current);
      }
    }
  }
  // now assemble the result and return it.
  sentence = '';
  for (i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    sentence += lines[i];
    // add separator if not the last line
    if (i < len -1) {
      sentence += separator;
    }
  }
  return sentence;
}
```